# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds. Java Spiral Program

Tags: java, arrays, loops, 2d, spiral

I keep getting the error ArrayIndexOutOfBounds: 4 on line 21. The line is Spiral[VIndx][HIndx]=number. This program is supposed to create a spiral of numbers when given a certain dimension. For example, if given the dimension 3, a 3x3 2d array that spirals numbers. Here's what the spiral should be:

7 8 9

6 1 2

5 4 3

Why aren't my loops working?

```
   import java.util.*;import java.io.*;
   public class Spiral{

   public static void Spiral(int dimensions, int [][] Spiral)
   {
   int endNumber = (int)Math.pow(dimensions, 2);
   int number = 1;

   int rightmovement = 1;
   int downmovement = 1;
   int leftmovement = 2;
   int upmovement = 2;

   int HIndx = (dimensions-1)/2;
   int VIndx = (dimensions-1)/2;

   while(number<=endNumber)
   {
for(int i = 0;i<=rightmovement;i++)
{
   Spiral[VIndx][HIndx]=number;
   number++;
   HIndx++;
   if(number==endNumber)break;
}
rightmovement++;


for(int i = 0;i<=downmovement;i++)
{
Spiral[VIndx][HIndx]=number;
number++;   
VIndx++;
if(number==endNumber)break;
}
downmovement++;


for(int i = 1;i<=leftmovement;i++)
{
 Spiral[VIndx][HIndx]=number;
number++;   
HIndx--;
if(number==endNumber)break;
}
leftmovement++;


for(int i = 1;i<=upmovement;i++)
{
 Spiral[VIndx][HIndx]=number;
number++;   
VIndx--;
if(number==endNumber)break;
}
upmovement++;

 }

 }
 public static void main(String[]args)throws IOException
 {
 File file = new File("spiral.txt");
 Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
 String [] numbers = new String [2];
 int i =0;
 while (input.hasNextLine())
 {
 String line = input.nextLine();
 numbers[i]=line;
 i++;
 }
 int dimensions = 0;
 input.close();
 int [][] Spiral = new int [dimensions][dimensions];  

 dimensions = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
 int range = Integer.parseInt(numbers[1]);
  if(dimensions%2==0)
  {
    dimensions+=1;
  }

 Spiral(dimensions, Spiral);

 for(i = 0; i<dimensions;i++){
   for(int j = 0; j<dimensions;j++){ 
   System.out.println(Spiral[i][j]);
                       }
        }

     }
           }
```

Comment: You naming convention keeps on confusing me!!!

Comment: Have you tried to use debugger ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your loop condition should use `<` rather than `<=`.

Second, if you think about the spiral you'll realize that you always end with a right movement. You hit the `break` at the first time you have

```
if(number==endNumber)break;
```

but this doesn't exit you out of the `while` loop - this only leaves the `for` loop. So then you go into the down movement `for` loop and get the index out of bounds exception.

Third, you need to first enter the center number before the loop.

Additionally, `rightmovement`, `leftmovement`, ... should all be increased by 2 each time. The reason for this is easier to see in a larger grid.

```
21 22 23 24 25
20  7  8  9 10
19  6  1  2 11
18  5  4  3 12
17 16 15 14 13
```

Notice the first right movement writes `2`, then the next one writes `8 9 10`, and the last one writes `22 23 24 25` and would have written `26` if you were to continue.

To fix the issue with `break` not leaving the `while` loop, just change it into a `return` statement.